# if/else по значению в выбранной строке datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма с button и textbox'ами. 
По нажатию кнопки открывается вторая форма с DataGridView и кнопкой "Выбрать". Пользователь выбирает нужную строку в гриде, нажимает кнопку "Выбрать", форма закрывается, а данные из выбранной строки попадают в textbox'ы первой формы.

Как добавить сюда следующее условие?

*Если в выбранной строке в 8 ячейке встречается слово "Да", вытащить данные в textbox'ы нельзя и появляется MessageBox о предупреждении?*

Код кнопки "Выбрать":

```
//Кнопка выбрать
        private void SELECT_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Если выделена строка
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0) 
            {
                //Получаем значения в текущей строке
                int currentRow = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow];

                //Закрываем форму
                this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Вы не выделили строку!");
        }
```

Comment: делать окно модальным и обработать закрытие окна а данные можно записать кудато что то типа сервписа по передачи данных между окнами был бы wpf  то это вообще плевое дело было бы

Comment: Начать чтение [отсюда](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/22.4.php), ключевое слово `interface IValidatableObject`

Answer (score 0):

Както так пробни

```
   Form f = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().FirstOrDefault(form => form.Name == "form1");
                if (f != null)
                    f.textBox1.Text = "Text";
```

ну да и это код выполнить при закрытии 2 окна

Comment: Причем здесь закрытие окна? Вопрос был как добавить условие в обработчик кнопки.